# How to use grepl in every row?

Tags: r, grepl

I'm trying to search for a pattern in a text using `grepl`. The problem is that my pattern is a list of names and my text is also a list of texts of the same length. I would like to build a loop that goes over each row and search for a given name in the corresponding text.

**edit** for clarity

So for example, in this data:

```
pat <- c("mary", "john", "anthony") 
text <- c("This is a long text about anthony", "This is another long text about john", "This is a final text about mary").
```

I would like search `"mary"` in the first text, and then `"john"` in the second, and finally `"anthony"` in the third one.

Comment: Try `grepl(paste0(pat,collapse="|"), text, ignore.case = TRUE)`.

Comment: Thank you! I've seen this answer before and it's not solving my problem. I can explain myself better. I don't want to search for ALL the names in the texts, just ONE name in the corresponding text. So for example, in this data:  pat <- c("mary", "john", "anthony") 
text <- c("This is a long text about anthony", "This is another long text about john", "This is a final text about mary").                                                          I would like search "mary" in the first text, and then "john" in the second, and finally "anthony" in the third one.

Comment: Please edit your question and add that explanation there. It makes easier for people to help you.

Comment: Thank you! I've just edited it.

Answer (score 9):

```
pat <- c("mary", "john", "anthony") 
text <- c("This is a long text about anthony", "This is another long text about john", "This is a final text about mary")
```

The `Map` or `mapply` functions will do this:

```
Map(grepl,pat,text)
```

(this returns a list, which you can `unlist`)

or

```
mapply(grepl,pat,text)
```

(automatically simplifies) or

```
n <- length(pat)
res <- logical(n)
for (i in seq(n)) {
  res[i] <- grepl(pat[i],text[i])
}
```

Comment: Nice solution +1

Comment: Thanks! In the mapply version, how can I add the "ignore.case=TRUE" argument? I need it because in some texts some names appear with upper case and in others with lower case.

Comment: You can add parameters for mapply with the MoreArgs parameter: `mapply(grepl,pat,text,MoreArgs=list(ignore.case=TRUE))`.

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative is to use `Vectorize`

```
Vectorize(grepl)(pattern = pat, x = text, ignore.case = TRUE)
#   mary    john anthony 
#  FALSE    TRUE   FALSE
```

Comment: Extremely useful function, this worked like a charm and has many applications, should be accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

With your new sample data, you could do:

```
pat <- c("mary", "john", "anthony") 
text <- c("This is a long text about anthony", "This is another long text about john", "This is a final text about mary")

sapply(1:length(pat), function(x) grepl(pat[x],text[x]))
```

which returns:

```
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is helpful, thank you. I added the argument "ignore.case=TRUE" in: sapply(1:length(pat), function(x) grepl(pat[x],text[x], ignore.case=TRUE)) because I needed to find names with both upper and lower case.